# Clustering algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering

I have sparse vectors and found that cosine similarity is very efficient to to measure the similarity. Now I want to cluster these vectors based on similarity. Hence, can someone please suggest/recommend clustering algorithms that make use of cosine similarity?

P.S.: I do not have a predefined number of clusters beforehand and want the clustering algorithm itself to decide it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_propagation

Comment: Thank you very much. As mentioned I do not have a predefined number of clusters beforehand :)

Comment: You did not. So estimate it?

Comment: Edited my question. Can't I let the clustering algorithm itself to decide the number of clusters? :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Comment: Thank you :) Is it based on cosine similarity or distance?

Comment: You can implement DBSCAN, OPTICS, HAC, ... all with similarities, too. There are fewer methods that can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your affinity matrix as a [weighted adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#weight) of a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) and apply [modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks))-based [community detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_Modularity) on that. Just note that modularity based algorithms have resolution problem i.e. finding very small communities is difficult in presence of large ones.